# Who is out if both batsmen end up at the same end and the fielders hit the stumps at that end?

Tags: rules, cricket

I have a query regarding a run out dismissal: Who is out in the following scenario:

The batsman runs, while his partner doesn't. Both batsmen end up at the non-striker end, and a fielder hits the stumps at this end. Then the non-striker leaves the crease, and runs to the striker end. No fielder hits the stump at the striker end?

What will be the result of this?

Answer (score 10):

Nobody is out. When the wicket was put down at the non-striker's end, the batsman who owned that ground (whichever reached that ground first) was in their ground so are not out. After that, no wicket is put down so there is no dismissal.

The batting team would also score one run as the batsmen exchanged ends.

For reference, see [Law 29 (Batsman out of his ground)](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-29-batsman-out-of-his-ground/) and [Law 38 (Run Out)](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-38-run-out/).